# Insert query exception "No value given for one or more required parameters"

Tags: c#, .net

Here i am adding 5 datas to the table(Registration), and it contains 6 six columns among that the ID is primary KEY indentity. But i am getting an exception that no value for one or more required parameters at "myCommand.ExecuteReader();" while trying to insert the other data columns.

```
public void SubmitClick(Object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    insertdata(FN.Text,LN.Text,DOB.Text,mailid.Text,username.Text);
}
public void insertdata(string fname, string sname, string dob ,string email ,string uname)
{

    //Connection string for the datbase
    string database = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= C:\Users\atchutharamkj\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\App_Data\Database3.accdb;Persist Security Info=True";
    OleDbConnection myConn = new OleDbConnection(database);
    string queryStr = @"Insert into Registration Values (fname , sname, dob , email, uname)";
    OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(queryStr, myConn);
    myCommand.Connection.Open();
    myCommand.ExecuteReader();
    myCommand.Connection.Close();

}
```

Comment: You are not passing parameters to `Command`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query is wrong and this way you are not passing anything to it.

Use parametrized queries like that:

```
public void SubmitClick(Object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    insertdata(FN.Text,LN.Text,DOB.Text,mailid.Text,username.Text);
}

public void insertdata(string fname, string sname, string dob ,string email ,string uname)
{
    string database = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= C:\Users\atchutharamkj\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\App_Data\Database3.accdb;Persist Security Info=True";
    OleDbConnection myConn = new OleDbConnection(database);

    string queryStr = @"Insert into Registration(FirstName,LastName,DOB,[E-Mail],Username ) Values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(queryStr, myConn);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", fname);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sname", sname);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", dob);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", uname);

    myCommand.Connection.Open();
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    myCommand.Connection.Close();
}
```

More about passing parameters to OleDB see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx).

Comment: I have tried this parameters method too, but i got an exception as " Number of query values and destination fields are not the same". But i am sure that i have 6 columns ( ID, Firstname,Lastname,DOB,Email,Username) and the ID is the identity so i am not including that in the query.

Comment: That means `Registration` table has more columns than you supplied values for. You may explicitly write in your query column names like `Insert into Registration (FirstName, SureName, Dob, Email, Username) Values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)` or so.

Comment: `string queryStr = @"Insert into Registration(FirstName,LastName,DOB,E-Mail,Username ) Values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";` i changed the query like this but it tell there is syntax ERROR in INSERT INTO statement.

Comment: I think you have to put `E-Mail` inside square brackets: `[E-Mail]` and maybe `Username` if it is registered keyword in your DBMS

Comment: i made the changes , now i get no exception. thanks for guiding me @gzaxx . But i noticed there is no change in the database (access).

Comment: You had one more mistake in your code. Change `myCommand.ExecuteReader();` to `myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();` as reader returns rows to read but you are inserting data not retrieving.

Comment: I changed that into `myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();` but no use , its still the DB is empty

Comment: Try running this query with values directly in Access and see if it inserts something.